# How to display different records on text fields from different tables with only 1 dataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, textbox

With only 1 dataGridView, I can display different records in database from 3 tables(one at a time) based on their corresponding button click (user_tb, project_tb, test_tb)

- I want to be able to display records on their corresponding **text field** by clicking on their respective table records.

1) click show_user btn > user records show in dataGridView1 > click on a user record > user_id appear in the given `assign_user_txtbx.Text`

2) click show_bug btn > bug records show in dataGridView1 > click on a bug record > bug_id appear in the given `assign_bug_txtbx.Text`

3) click show_test btn > test records show in dataGridView1 > click on a test record > test_id appear in the given `assign_test_txtbx.Text`

```
private void multi_dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender,   DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow Row = this.multi_dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            assign_user_txtbx.Text = Row.Cells["user_id"].Value.ToString();

        } // end of if statement

        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow Row = this.multi_dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            assign_project_txtbx.Text = Row.Cells["project_id"].Value.ToString();

        } // end of if statement

        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow Row = this.multi_dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            assign_test_txtbx.Text = Row.Cells["test_id"].Value.ToString();

        } // end of if statement
    }
```

Problem is that Im using only 1 dataGridView

Comment: change the DataSource of the DataGridView when clicking on your buttons should do it

Comment: could u explain in more details please, I can display the database onto the dataGridView just fine...I only time I click on my button is to display my database onto the dataGridView...

Comment: If I understand your question correct, you want to show different data in the DataGridView after clicking on a button. So in the click, change the datasource of the DataGridView to another resultset. If that is not your problem, please explain better in your question what you need and what ur exact problem is. Currently your question is vague

Comment: I already can show different data in the DataGridView, what I want is when I click/select one record from the DataGridView, I want that specific data to be shown on its corresponding text field. Problem is that since I already display a database onto the DataGridView, when i select a record, its give me that error 'assign_project_txtbx.Text = Row.Cells["project_id"].Value.ToString()'; data not exist since I need to retrieve that one from another database.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking. I thnk you need to fill a textbox with a value from the selected row, but since you change the content of the DataGridView at runtime, the value you need to fetch may also differ.
If so then maybe something like this can get you started ?

```
private void multi_dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow Row = this.multi_dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        if (Row.Cells["user_id"] != null)
            assign_user_txtbx.Text = Row.Cells["user_id"].Value.ToString();
        else if (Row.Cells["project_id"] != null)
            assign_project_txtbx.Text = Row.Cells["project_id"].Value.ToString();
        else if (Row.Cells["test_id"] != null)
            assign_test_txtbx.Text = Row.Cells["test_id"].Value.ToString();
    } // end of if statement
}
```

Another way is to set some kind of flag when you click on the buttons that change the view on the datagridview, and use that flag in the `if .. else` part